# Program that prints itself even if the source file is deleted

Tags: c

I came across a program in C that prints itself even if the source file is deleted. But I couldn't find out how it works. Following is the code for this

```
char *p="char *p=%c%s%c;main() {printf(p,34,p,34);}";
main() {printf(p,34,p,34);}
```

Can anyone help me with this by explaining each steps?

Comment: Which part of this is unclear?  Do you understand how `printf` works?

Comment: No, I don't understand how this printf() works...

Comment: In that case, I suggest you learn the basics first (in this case, specifically what `printf` does with its arguments).  Once you understand that, then it should be clear how the above code works!

Comment: This is a ['quine'](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quine_(computing)).

Comment: **To those inclined to edit the program text**: Don't reformat the code; it breaks the program!  The format is crucial.  If you reformat it, you don't understand the code.

Comment: hi, @JonathanLeffler can you please tell me how this printf() works...thanks...

Comment: possible duplicate of [C/C++ program that prints its own source code as its output](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10238670/c-c-program-that-prints-its-own-source-code-as-its-output)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This version of a C ['quine'](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quine_%28computing%29) or self-reproducing program is not strictly valid C89, let alone anything newer.  However, it will work on most systems.

The key to understanding it is to know that character 34 is the double quote, `"`.

```
char *p="char *p=%c%s%c;main() {printf(p,34,p,34);}";
main() {printf(p,34,p,34);}
```

The `printf()` prints using the string `p` as the format string, with arguments `34` (or double quote), `p` again, and 34 (again).

```
printf("char *p=%c%s%c;main() {printf(p,34,p,34);}", 34, p, 34);
```

which yields:

```
char *p="char *p=%c%s%c;main() {printf(p,34,p,34);}";main() {printf(p,34,p,34);}
```

and when that's recompiled and run, it reproduces itself.

This version is compliant with Standard C:

```
#include <stdio.h>
const char*s="#include <stdio.h>%cconst char*s=%c%s%c;%cint main(void){printf(s,10,34,s,34,10,10);}%c";
int main(void){printf(s,10,34,s,34,10,10);}
```

It uses the fact that newline `'\n'` is ^J is character code 10 as well as 34 is double quote `"`.

Comment: Is there no way to avoid dependeny on ascii? `'\n'` and `'"'` would make that portable :)

Comment: @JensGustedt: Interesting question — I'm not sure...The Lua and Ruby quines on the Wikipedia page manage to avoid ASCII codes.  The other examples do not.  If you're going to avoid ASCII, you probably have to use something other than `printf()`, or you have to include something like `char q = '"';` in the string and in the program code.

Answer (score 1):

If the printf() in the program above were replaced with the one below, would you understand it?

```
printf("char *p=%c%s%c;main() {printf(p,34,p,34);}",
      34, "a string", 34);
```

Comment: The `34` is "linked" to the `%c` in the format string. That simply prints the character with value `34` in the encoding used by the environment (in ASCII it's a quote).