# Quine create and execute file

Tags: c, printf, execv, quine

I am creating a [Quine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quine_(computing)) in C and where i need to create a new c file and then compile it and execute it.

I made a simple snippet to understand why it's not working.

My guess is that `execv` start the command before fprintf is done writing but i put a sleep and it's wasn't working too.

(All my apologize for this ugliest code but it's not the goal)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main()
{
    char *cmd[100]= {"sh", "-c", "\"gcc tmp.c && ./a.out\""};

    fprintf(fopen("tmp.c", "w"), "#include <stdio.h>\nint main(){puts(\"Hello World\");}");
    execv("/bin/sh", cmd);
    return (0);
}
```

Output

```
sh: gcc tmp.c && ./a.out: No such file or directory
```

Any idea ?

Comment: Isn't the object of a quine program to recreate its own source code as the output when it is run?  See [Program that prints its own source code as its output](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10238670/) and [Program that prints itself even if the source file is deleted](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15325385/) as examples; there are more in the 'Related questions' list on the RHS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your argument array `cmd` is not terminated with a NULL pointer. Also, it has the quote issue.

You should also close the file before `execv()` call. The reason you are not seeing anything in the file is because fprintf() buffering. While all the open files are closed at process exit, you are exec'ing before that.

```
int main(void)
{

   char *cmd[]= {"sh", "-c", "gcc tmp.c && ./a.out", (char*)0};

    FILE *fp = fopen("tmp.c", "w");
    if (!fp) {
       perror("fopen");
       exit(1);
    }

    fprintf(fp, "#include <stdio.h>\nint main(){puts(\"Hello World\");}");
    fclose(fp);
    execv("/bin/sh", cmd);
    perror("execv");
    return (0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

when you're calling your shell in a normal shell you do:

```
sh -c "gcc tmp.c && ./a.out"
```

(`sh -c gcc tmp.c && ./a.out` works in my shell but not yours as your comments are stating)

So it means that you have to pass the arguments not as much quoted to `execv` or they're interpreted as a single argument like if you did:

```
sh -c \""gcc tmp.c && ./a.out\""
```

proposed fix:

```
char *cmd[100]= {"sh", "-c", "gcc tmp.c && ./a.out", NULL};
```

BTW: don't forget to `fclose` your file or `tmp.c` may be zero.
BTW2: thanks to usr, a `NULL` was missing: edited.

Fully fixed code proposal:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
int main()
{
    char *cmd[100]= {"sh", "-c", "gcc tmp.c && ./a.out", NULL};
    FILE *outfile = fopen("tmp.c", "w");
    if (!outfile) {printf("cannot open output file\n");exit(1);}

    fprintf(outfile, "#include <stdio.h>\nint main(){puts(\"Hello World\");}");
    fclose(outfile);  // required else file remains open
    execv("/bin/sh", cmd);
    return (0);
}
```

Comment: `sh -c gcc tmp.c && ./a.out` not working in my shell

Comment: I just thought i should use `system()` !

Comment: yes, `system` is nice too. But the quote thing will act the same. See & test my edit. Quoting hell !!!

Comment: with your option, the file is not filled

Comment: not my fault: check my edit. you're not closing your output file.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre The array `cmd` must end with a null pointer too.