# How does this quine work?

Tags: c, quine

I just came across this quine question, but no one really went into how it works: [C/C++ program that prints its own source code as its output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10238670/c-c-program-that-prints-its-own-source-code-as-its-output)

```
char*s="char*s=%c%s%c;main(){printf(s,34,s,34);}";main(){printf(s,34,s,34);}
```

What I especially don't understand is the following has the same output even though I changed the ints:

```
char*s="char*s=%c%s%c;main(){printf(s,34,s,34);}";main(){printf(s,5,s,11);}
```

It still prints the 34s! Can someone walk me through this step by step?

Comment: What does it print after `char*s=` and before the second `;main(){`? (where the quote marks should be)

Comment: What does this have to do with the title?

Comment: `char*s="blah";` is invalid as C++ code.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Let's start by formatting the code to span multiple lines. This breaks the fact that it's a quine, but makes it easier to see what's happening:

```
char* s = "char*s=%c%s%c;main(){printf(s,34,s,34);}";

main() { 
   printf(s, 34, s, 34);
}
```

Essentially, this is a declaration of a string `s` that's a `printf`-formatted string, followed by a declaration of a function `main` that invokes `printf` on four arguments. (This definition of `main` uses the old-fashioned "implicit `int`" rule in C where functions are assumed to have `int` as a return type unless specified otherwise. I believe this is currently deprecated in C and know for certain that this is not legal C++ code.)

So what exactly is this `printf` call doing? Well, it might help to note that 34 is the ASCII code for a double-quote, so the line

```
printf(s, 34, s, 34);
```

is essentially

```
printf(s, '"', s, '"');
```

This means "print the string `s` with arguments `"`, `s`, and `"`." So what's `s`? It's shown here:

```
char* s = "char*s=%c%s%c;main(){printf(s,34,s,34);}";
```

This follows a common self-reference trick. Ignoring the `%c%s%c` part, this is basically a string representation of the rest of the program. The `%c%s%c` part occurs at the point where it becomes self-referential.

So what happens if you call `printf(s, '"', s, '"')`? This will fill in the placeholder `%c%s%c` with `"char*s=%c%s%c;main(){printf(s,34,s,34);}"`, which is the string contents of the string `s`. Combined with the rest of the string `s`, this therefore proints

```
char*s="char*s=%c%s%c;main(){printf(s,34,s,34);}";main(){printf(s,34,s,34);";
```

which is the source code of the program. I think this is kinda neat - the closest English translation of a general Quine program I know is "print this string, the second time in quotes" (try it - see what happens!), and this basically does exactly that.

You were asking why changing the numbers to 5 and 11 didn't change that 34 was being printed. That's correct! The string literal `s` has 34 hard-coded into it, so changing the 5 and 11 in the call to `printf` won't change that. What it will do is no longer print the quotation marks around the inside of the string `s` and instead print non-printing characters.

Comment: Thanks for such a clear explanation of what was going on.